# Initializing a Highmap using Highcharts.Map

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I am trying to plot the Highmap using the constructor i.e. Highcharts.Map.
The following is the link to my jsfiddle code:

http://jsfiddle.net/rt4x9ngo/3/

```
var options1 = {
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
},
        series : []
};
var drawMap = function () {
        var newSeriesData = {
                name: 'Countries',
                mapData:  Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['custom/world']),
                color: '#E0E0E0',
                enableMouseTracking: false,           
                            };
                options1.series.push(newSeriesData);    
                var chart = new Highcharts.Map(options1);
};
drawMap();
```

I followed the method used in the following jsfiddle link :

http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/pUM7s/

I am unable to find out what is the thing I am missing here.

Comment: You have to wait for document ready. Wrap this code in `$(function() { /* your code */ });`.

Comment: This wrap thing worked for me. But I have a doubt that it worked for the charts without wrapping and why it didn't worked for maps? and please add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Generally you should init charts when your DOM is loaded.